# Why can't a nonstatic method be called from a static one?

Tags: c++

Let:

```
class CLASS{
    void foo() {};
    static void staticFoo() { foo(); }
};
```

Why would calling a nonstatic method from a static one be a problem? How do I go around this?

Comment: Do you know the difference between `static` and nonstatic members?

Comment: Why do you need to call a nonstatic method from a static method? What do you think this should do?

Comment: non-static needs a `this` pointer.  A static function doesn't have one.  You don't "go around" it - it's fundamentally meaningless.

Comment: @MooingDuck Static members don't need to be called on particular objects/instances of that class, while nonstatic members do.

Comment: @Chriss555888: So which `CLASS` will `foo` be called on?

Comment: @MooingDuck which object not which class

Comment: @MooingDuck If you put it like this, it makes sense, but why couldn't `foo` be called statically, if the call is made from a static function?

Comment: @Chriss555888: Because which `CLASS` would `foo` be called on? There is no `CLASS` to call `foo`. That's why you can't call it. It literally doesn't make sense to try.

Comment: Example: `class Person { void sing() {}; static void makeChoirSing(){ sing();}};` _who is singing_? You don't want every person on the planet to sing, just the choir. How can that method know who's in the choir?  This would be easier to point out if you showed real code and real problem.

Comment: Rather than methods, think about the difference between `static` attributes and non static attributes. By definition, `static` method can access to `static` attributes only. Hence a non static method (which can access to non static attributes) cannot be called from a static method. There would be no way for the non static method to know which attributes should be used, as it has is no reference to an instance of the class.

Comment: @MooingDuck Well it depends how `sing` is implemented. `class Person` probably has member variables which are most likely set to a default value. If `sing` would be called form a `static makeChoirSing`, then `sing` could be called statically as well, using the default values of `class Person` members. While I now understand why there is this restriction in C++, I can't see a reason why such a situation couldn't work.

Comment: @Valentino Is it good practice to declare both `static` and `nonstatic` members in the same class then?

Comment: @Chriss555888: Wait, "using the default values of class Person"?  Oh. Then _in your particular case_ all you need to do is have `staticFoo` make a new `Person` instance, and then call `foo` on that then.  This isn't always possible, since not all classes _have_ defaults, but it sounds like it is for your case.

Comment: @Chriss555888 Yes, a class can indeed have static and non static members if needed. There is nothing against it.

Comment: @ MooingDuck That's what I needed. Thanks

Comment: There are two bits of information needed to call a non-static member function.   One is the name of the member function.   The other is the object it acts on.   For example, `some_affected_object.non_static_function()`.      A static member function is not associated with any particular object (i.e. it does not have `some_affected_object`) by default.    Of course, it is possible for the static function to create the object, or find a reference to one.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by your question, it appears that you are not very familiar with object oriented programming. Writing C++ classes and not knowing object oriented programming is not the best idea. It's also not something we can sum up in a StackOverflow answer. It's best if you search for this topic and learn at least the basics before continuing. It actually would take less time that you'd imagine to get familiar with the basics.

This MIT class's presentation on object oriented programming is decent. [Object oriented programming in C++](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-088-introduction-to-c-memory-management-and-c-object-oriented-programming-january-iap-2010/lecture-notes/MIT6_088IAP10_lec04.pdf)

But to answer your question: why can't we call up a non-static method from a static method. Well when you define a C++ class, you're describing the model, or blueprint for making instances of *something*. For example, you could define a class `Animal` like this:

```
class Animal {
public:
  void set_name(std::string name) { this->name_ = name; }
  const std::string& get_name() const { return this->name_; }

private:
  std::string name_;
};
```

We obviously have methods to set and get the name of this `Animal` class. Note that much like in the real world, we don't just name the abstract idea of animals, we'd name our own pet or some known specific animal, that happens to be one instance of an animal. This might receive criticism but you can kinda think of it as the difference between `dog` and `the dog`. The latter is a specific `dog` that all involved parties are aware of. That's why methods `set_name` and `get_name` need to know **which** animal you're talking about.

Consider this:

```
Animal my_dog;
my_dog.set_name("stripes");

Animal my_cat;
my_cat.set_name("katz");
```

The method `set_name` updates the name of `my_dog` and `my_cat`. We had to tell the `set_name` which instance we're talking about. Methods like these are instance methods, you can have a pointer to yourself which in C++ is designated by `this`. That's how you can update attributes about different instances. A static method doesn't receive this context and therefor won't be able to call instance methods unless of course it has access to one of these instances. For example:

```
static void print_animal(const Animal& animal) {
  std::cout << animal.get_name() << std::endl;
}
```

After all of this, hopefully it makes sense why we can't just call `Animal::set_name`.

Answer (score -1):

> Why can't a nonstatic method be called from a static one?

A non-static member function **can** be called from a static member function.

> Why would calling a nonstatic method from a static one be a problem?

It's not a problem. The problem is that you've not invoked the non-static member function on an object. Non-static member functions cannot be invoked without an object argument.

The syntaxes to invoke a non-static member function are following:

```
instance.mem_fun(arguments);
pointer->mem_fun(arguments);
```

Non-static member functions are special in that they can invoke other non-static member functions without explicit instance argument. The argument is implicitly `this`. Static member functions don't have `this`, and the exception doesn't apply to them.

> How do I go around this?

Use one of the syntaxes shown above. You need to consider what instance you intend to use as the object argument of the non-static member function.

> but why couldn't `foo` be called statically ...

Because `foo` is a **non**-static member function. Non-static member functions cannot be called statically.

> ... if the call is made from a static function?

Where the function is called from has no effect on whether it can be called statically.

Comment: this answer feels pretty pedantic for someone who is obviously quite new.  If nothing else, the answer backwards - saving the part that's helpful to the person for the end.